# Range of trigonometric functions in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, range, trigonometry

```
from math import * 

def f(a,b,c,d): 
    alpha = arccos(a/d)
    beta = pi - arcsin(a+b/d) 
    theta= arccos(a/c)
    eta= arccos (a+c/b+d) 
    return (alpha, beta, theta, eta)
```

I was thinking during this that there there is a possibility that the terms inside `arccos` and `arcsin` would be out of range. so I should check in every function if the terms are within the range or not i.e. by use `if` statement example: `if a/d>1 or a/d<1:   alpha=arccos(a/d)` but if I want to make this for every line, this will make the code looks ugly, plus what in case we have many trigonometric functions. Is there a function or a method to do that for all cosine and sines used in python?

(Note that this function above is written randomly)

Comment: What error are you getting, please include a stack trace of the actual error

Comment: can you put the error ? and an example of the output in the post ?

Comment: "(Note that this function above is written randomly)" Well that doesn't really help us help you an awful lot...

Comment: @Grismar   sorry i was writing something at first then delete it and I forget it. I fix it

Comment: @Sharim why `*`? This is not a good practice, `from math import arccos, arcsin, pi` is sufficient ;)

Comment: You can't just skip the calculation when something is out of range; you have to think about what you want to happen in that case, which is going to be different in different cases. If you can come up with a common behavior for your use cases, you can make your own trigonometric functions that wrap the standard one (perhaps put them in a module called mymath or something more descriptive).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, please don't use examples that are "written randomly". An example of why is that the functions in math are called `acos` and `asin`, not `arccos` and `arcsin` and by actually running the code you would spot this.

`math.acos` raises `ValueError` with the message `"math domain error"` when given an argument > 1.  You can catch all instances of this like so.

```
from math import acos, asin

def f(a,b,c,d):
    try:
        alpha = acos(a/d)
        beta = pi - asin(a+b/d) 
        theta = acos(a/c)
        eta = acos (a+c/b+d) 
        return alpha, beta, theta, eta
    except ValueError:
        print("Got an argument outside [-1, 1]")
```

Comment: thank you but that's strange, I already used `arccos` in my code and it's behaving well

Comment: Which version of Python are you using?  The `numpy` package uses the name `arccos`, is there any chance you imported from there, or some other math/science library?

Comment: Python 3.7 and I just included `import math`

Comment: That's very odd, I can't reproduce that and it's not [documented](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/math.html). Anyway, it's aside from the main question so I suppose it doesn't matter for now!